# Macbook Pro 2016 freezing after MacOS High Sierra 10.13.2 update

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, software-update, performance

I have a Macbook Pro 2016, maxed out. After I updated to High Sierra, I experienced two freezes within the first day. In both instances, the screen freezes, except for the mouse, and the fan gradually ramps up to max speeds.

The first time I experienced the freeze, I had a lot of programs running, however, I only had a few programs running during the second freeze.

Are there know issues with High Sierra, and is there something I can do to troubleshoot them?

Comment: What doies activity monitor show in high use for memory. Mighht help to use something like iStat menus to show as it happens

Answer (score 2):

Try resetting your System Management Controller (SMC).
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295